# Calculate date time difference python

Tags: python, date, time, difference

I am writing timediff function to calculate the time (seconds) difference between 2 giving date time

```
def timediff(time1, time2):
    timeformat = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S'
    #time1="01MAR2016:07:11:53"
    #time2="01MAR2016:16:28:38"

    try:
        date_object1 = datetime.strptime(time1, timeformat)
        date_object2 = datetime.strptime(time2, timeformat)
    except ValueError:
        print "time1 format: " + repr(time1)
        print "time2 format: " + repr(time2)
        raise                      

    return abs((date_object2 - date_object1).seconds)
```

It seems to not take the "month, date, year" to the calculation. It gives the right calculation if it is in the same "month, date, year"

```
>>> t1="01MAR2016:07:11:53"
>>> t2="01MAR2016:16:28:38"
>>> timediff(t1, t2)
33405
```

However with different "month, date, year", it gives the wrong answer. This only calculates time difference ~18hrs (which gives ~65k seconds)

```
>>> t1="02APR2016:06:43:51"
>>> t2="06APR2016:00:58:03"
>>> timediff(t1, t2)
65652
```

Or 24hrs different it gives 0

```
>>> t1="01MAR2016:07:11:53"
>>> t2="02MAR2016:07:11:53"
>>> timediff(t1, t2)
0
```

The datetime takes the time format I gives

```
>>> t1="01MAR2016:07:11:53"
>>> t2="02MAR2016:07:11:53"
>>> datetime.strptime(t1, timeformat)
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 1, 7, 11, 53)
>>> datetime.strptime(t2, timeformat)
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 2, 7, 11, 53)
```

Am I missing anything?

I have another alternative which convert date time to seconds. But still want to know why this method doesnt work.

My alternative

```
def timediff(time1, time2):
    timeformat = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S'
    t1 = datetime.strptime(time1, timeformat)
    t2 = datetime.strptime(time2, timeformat)

    return abs(time.mktime(t1.timetuple()) - time.mktime(t2.timetuple()))
```

Example:

```
>>> t2
'02MAR2016:07:11:53'
>>> t1
'01MAR2016:07:11:53'
>>> timediff(t1,t2)
86400.0
```

Comment: you are using `.seconds` instead of `.total_seconds()`

Comment: You are right! Thanks for the clarify. Didnt know there is .total_seconds()

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `total_seconds()` and not `seconds`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> f = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S'
>>> t1 = '01MAR2016:07:11:53'
>>> t2 = '02MAR2016:07:11:53'
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, f)
>>> d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, f)
>>> print(d2-d1)
1 day, 0:00:00
>>> print((d2-d1).total_seconds())
86400.0
>>> print((d2-d1).seconds)
0
```

Comment: beat me to writing an answer, well to add here is documentation links to [`timedelta.seconds`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.resolution) "Between 0 and 86399 inclusive" and link to [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds)