# How can I change the format to perform date arithmetic?

Tags: python

I would like to obtain an integer (days) from the difference of 2 dates

```
end= (pd.datetime.today()-BDay(1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
start= dt.datetime.strptime(4/4/2016, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

fter seeking in SO I found this post so I tried the same methology unsuccesfully 
[Calculate date time difference python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928815/calculate-date-time-difference-python)

```
 difference=end-start
 print(difference.total_days())

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I don't know how exactly change this format  given that is a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert your dates to strings:

```
end = pd.datetime.today()-BDay(1)
start = dt.datetime.strptime('4/4/2016', '%m/%d/%Y')
difference = end - start
```